# Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION

Tags: android, push, android-c2dm

I'm trying to implement push notifications in my app, but it seems that my C2DMReceiver is not working. I tried every solution I could find. Here is what I have:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<permission android:name="com.my.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"   android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.my.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<activity>....</activity>

<service android:name=".C2DMReceiver"/>
<receiver 
          android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver"
          android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        <category android:name="com.my.app"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
         <category android:name="com.my.app"/>
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

In my onCreate method I use:
    C2DMessaging.register(this, "mymail@gmail.com");

```
String id = C2DMessaging.getRegistrationId(this);
```

And id is always empty.
Looking at the LogCat, I can see **Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION** So, what should I do?Thanks)

Comment: hm that looks exactly as the code that is working for me - can you give the full manifest? especially interested in the package="XXX" part ...

Comment: Could you please post the **register** method from C2DMessaging?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `android:name` in your `receiver` tag from `com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver` to `com.my.app.YourReceiverClassName`, and make sure your sender e-mail and server side login e-mail are the same.

Comment: I also use com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver for my app and it works there - so that cannot be the cause

Answer (score 1):

The `android:name` in your receiver has to specify the path to your class that implements the receiver. I am sure that your `C2DMBroadcastReceiver` class is not in the `com.google.android.c2dm` package, as I see below your are using a `com.my.app` package.

Create a C2DMBroadcastReceiver class in, for example, `com.my.app.receiver` and specify the receiver's `adroid:name` as:

```
<receiver 
      android:name="com.my.app.receiver.C2DMBroadcastReceiver"
      android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      ......
</receiver>
```